# Ocaml merge Hash tables

Tags: data-structures, merge, ocaml, hashtable

I would like to merge two same-type hash tables in Ocaml, so that the information of both of them gets stored in a single table. Imagine, something like:

```
  type tabType = (string, variable) Hashtbl.t

  let tabExample:tabType = Hashtbl.create 1000 in
  let tab1 = do_stuff tabExample a true in
  let tab2 = do_stuff tabExample a false in
  let tabFinal = tab1@tab2
```

Any idea?

Comment: If you use the Jane Street `Base` replacement standard library, there's [`Hashtbl.merge`](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/latest/doc/base/Base/Hashtbl/index.html#val-merge).

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot, JaneStreet has really done a lot for Ocaml. Would you help me one last time: how can I use (call) the library? I cannot found any `module Base` reference.

Comment: See https://opensource.janestreet.com/base/ and https://dev.realworldocaml.org/install.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have installed it in Opam with `opam install base`, but VisualStudio does not seem no recognise it when doing `open Base`. Thanks anyway!!

Comment: Oh, and https://dev.realworldocaml.org/maps-and-hashtables.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `tab1` can be overwritten and the entries in tab2 should replace the one in tab1,
this is just a `fold`:

```ml
  let merge ~into:tab1 tab2 =
    Hashtbl.fold (fun key elt () -> Hashtbl.replace tab1 key elt) tab2 ();
    tab1
```